# htaccess rewriterule precise (exact) match

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have a website on which I would like to redirect the page :
**website.com/component/users/profile**
to
**website.com/redirect**

However, I would like to allow to navigate to :

**website.com/component/users/profile?layout=edit**

The "?" seems to cause a problem. I found many solutions for doing this the other way around (go from link with "?" to a page without a "?").

What I have right now allows me to navigate to :
**website.com/component/users/profile**

but not to

**website.com/component/users/profile?layout=edit** (this is the one getting redirected)

I am trying to achieve the exact opposite.

The code in my htaccess file is :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^component/users/profile$
RewriteRule ^$ /redirect [L,R=301]
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is profile, a file or directory?

Comment: It's not exactly a file or a folder. This is a Joomla! website, so the links are being re-written in a SEO friendly way on the fly.

Comment: Check out the differences between `%{THE_REQUEST}`, `%{QUERY_STRING}` and `%{REQUEST_URI}` in the Apache documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html